# Why does `format_args!()` ignore truncation? How to truncate without allocation then?

Tags: rust

Why does this work?

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("{:.3}", "this is just a test");
}
```

prints => `thi`

While this doesn't?

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("{:.3}", format_args!("this is just a test"));
}
```

prints => `this is just a test`

Here's a [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b904b86a8de7a7dcd063ab9223418310).

For a little more context, I’m interested in the reasoning behind it, and a way to do it without any allocations.

I'm developing a [terminal game](https://github.com/rsalmei/ballbounce/) in Rust, where I have a `write!` which shows some statistics about the rendering and game loop, and that text can be quite long. Now that I read the terminal size and adjust its output accordingly, I need to truncate that output, but without any allocations.
I thought I was super clever when I refactored this:

```rust
write!(
  stdout,
  "{} ({} {} {}) {}",
  ...
)
```

into this:

```rust
write!(
  stdout,
  "{:.10}", // simulate only 10 cols in terminal.
  format_args!(
    "{} ({} {} {}) {}",
    ...
  )
)
```

How unfortunate, it doesn’t work… How to do that without allocating a String?

Comment: Significantly changing the question after receiving multiple answers is unfair to the people who have already put effort into answering the original question. I encourage you to accept an answer for the original *why* question, and ask a new question about your *how*.

Comment: I just included more context, to explain _why_ I wanted that. I think the _how_ was implicit since the beginning. Because _why_ would I want to know why something does not work, if I didn't want to know _how_ to make it work??

Comment: There's no "how" implicit in "why". Sure, one might infer that you wanted the *how*, but it's not *what you asked*, so if somebody puts a lot of effort into answering the *why* only to be upstaged by another answerer who swoops in with "just do X instead", that's unfair to the first answerer. If you want to know how, you should just ask "how?" Stack Overflow favors a direct approach.

Comment: This is why I personally never bother to answer "why" questions: because it's never possible to guess *a priori* what level of explanation will satisfy the asker. Don't expect people to read your mind, especially when language and cultural barriers might be in play.

Comment: Ok @trentcl, I agree with you, you're right. I'll try to pay more attention to this next time. Don't need to argue about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For one thing, not every type obeys all formatting arguments:

```
println!("{:.3}", 1024);
```

```
1024
```

Second, `format_args!` serves as the backbone for all of the `std::fmt` utilities. From the docs on [`format_args`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/#format_args):

> This macro functions by taking a formatting string literal containing `{}` for each additional argument passed. `format_args!` prepares the additional parameters to ensure the output can be interpreted as a string and canonicalizes the arguments into a single type. Any value that implements the `Display` trait can be passed to `format_args!`, as can any `Debug` implementation be passed to a `{:?}` within the formatting string.
>
> This macro produces a value of type `fmt::Arguments`. This value can be passed to the macros within `std::fmt` for performing useful redirection. All other formatting macros (`format!`, `write!`, `println!`, etc) are proxied through this one. `format_args!`, unlike its derived macros, avoids heap allocations.
>
> You can use the `fmt::Arguments` value that `format_args!` returns in Debug and Display contexts as seen below. The example also shows that `Debug` and `Display` format to the same thing: the interpolated format string in `format_args!`.
>
> ```
> let debug = format!("{:?}", format_args!("{} foo {:?}", 1, 2));
> let display = format!("{}", format_args!("{} foo {:?}", 1, 2));
> assert_eq!("1 foo 2", display);
> assert_eq!(display, debug);
> ```

Looking at the source for `impl Display for Arguments`, it just ignores any formatting parameters. I couldn't find this explicitly documented anywhere, but I can think of a couple reasons for this:

- The arguments are already considered formatted. If you really want to format a formatted string, use `format!` instead.
- Since its used internally for multiple purposes, its probably better to keep this part simple; its already doing the format heavy-lifting. Attempting to make the thing responsible for formatting arguments itself accept formatting parameters sounds needlessly complicated.

---

> I'd really like to truncate some output without allocating any Strings, would you know how to do it?

You can write to a fixed-size buffer:

```
use std::io::{Write, ErrorKind, Result};
use std::fmt::Arguments;

fn print_limited(args: Arguments<'_>) -> Result<()> {
    const BUF_SIZE: usize = 3;
    let mut buf = [0u8; BUF_SIZE];
    let mut buf_writer = &mut buf[..];

    let written = match buf_writer.write_fmt(args) {
        // successfully wrote into the buffer, determine amount written
        Ok(_) => BUF_SIZE - buf_writer.len(),
        
        // a "failed to write whole buffer" error occurred meaning there was 
        // more to write than there was space for, return entire size.
        Err(error) if error.kind() == ErrorKind::WriteZero => BUF_SIZE,
        
        // something else went wrong
        Err(error) => return Err(error),
    };
    
    // Pick a way to print `&buf[..written]`
    println!("{}", std::str::from_utf8(&buf[..written]).unwrap());
    
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    print_limited(format_args!("this is just a test")).unwrap();
    print_limited(format_args!("{}", 123)).unwrap();
    print_limited(format_args!("{}", 'a')).unwrap();
}
```

```
thi
123
a
```

This was actually more involved than I originally thought. There might be a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: Thank you @kmdreko, I've included more context. I'd really like to truncate some output without allocating any Strings, would you know how to do it?

Comment: @rsalmei I updated my answer to address your scenario.

Comment: Very nice! Thanks a lot @kmdreko!

Comment: Actually @kmdreko, it seems your original thought does work, why you think it was so much more involved? Oh I was ignoring the write! Result... Now I see your point.

Comment: @rsalmei it might be fine, I was unsure the behavior when writing less than the buffer size, but now that you bring it up I can't seem to break it either :? Maybe I should put it back...

Comment: Well, it is not a good practice anyway to ignore a `#[must_use]` result... I think this solution is fine.

Answer (score 0):

[I found this word here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/#precision)

> For non-numeric types, this can be considered a "maximum width". If the resulting string is longer than this width, then it is truncated down to this many characters and that truncated value is emitted with proper fill, alignment and width if those parameters are set.
> For integral types, this is ignored.
> For floating-point types, this indicates how many digits after the decimal point should be printed.

And `format_args` return type is `std::fmt::Arguments`,that is not `String` ,even though it looks like a string.

If you want to get same print contents,i think those code will work

```rust
/// unstable
println!("{:.3}", format_args!("this is just a test").as_str().unwrap());

println!("{:.3}", format_args!("this is just a test").to_string().as_str());
```

Comment: Thank you @will, I've included more context. I'd really like to truncate some output without allocating any Strings, would you know how to do it?